# How to display PHP-generated Google Chart in an HTML page

Tags: php, javascript, html, google-visualization

I have a file named `graph.php` on my server that reads dynamic content from a text file and displays a graph using Google Charts.

I also have a `graph.html` file on the server, which needs to embed this graph. How do I achieve this? I tried using javascript but it didn't work, I may be wrong:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"  
    src="http://mydomain/graph.php">
</script>
```

Comment: Aren't Google charts just images? What format is your PHP script outputting in?

Comment: yes, The graph is just an image , that gets displayed when I run the php... I need to put this in a htm file on the server... Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**: Accepted answer:

Use an iframe: `<iframe src="http://mydomain/graph.php" />`

---

Other method: if the graph file is just an image, then just:

```
 <img src="http://mydomain/graph.php" />
```

Make sure your headers are set correctly in that script, namely the `Content-type` header (which should be `image/png`), before any image data is printed.

Or, if the `graph.php` file has an `<img>` tag with the graph in it, just use: `<? include('graph.php') ?>`.

Comment: Okay, seems fine ... What if it's not just an img ... I foolishly have CSS and other scripts (for the template ) on the php file... should I remove that ? or is there another way to display the entire php on the htm  ?

Comment: As u may know, google chart itself requires <img src="<?php print $barChart->getUrl();  ?>" /> <br> hello
</body>
</html>   ... so the file also has html content ... 
 PLEase reply ... thx

Comment: I'd rename your `graph.html` to `display_graph.php`, and use the second method I described, with an `include`. The alternative is to somehow store (or calculate) the result of `$barChart->getUrl();` and simply use that in an `<img>` tag in `graph.html`.

Comment: We don't wanna modify the htm file as the app is deployed... I tried <? include('graph.php') ?>  on the HTM file ... is that right? it still didn't work ...  how to store the result of the getUrl() function? please help. thx

Comment: Can you use jQuery? Or heck, just use an iframe: `<iframe src="http://mydomain/graph.php" />`

Comment: You're the man Jimmy ! it works .. one more thing ..  when i used img src , it displays a broken img pic, when I right click on it and say view image, it shows the graph .... so wat was the error? content type ? it's in the script tag n it is image/png   .... thx .

Comment: If the format is `image/png`, the browser is looking for a very specific format of image to render and display. The HTML and CSS and such that was around that image was "corrupting" that format, leading to a broken image.